# Send php variable to external html

Tags: php, html

I have an external html file website.html and a php file test.php.
Now I want to display the variable $var = "someText" from test.php at the website for example here:

```
<h1><?php echo $fullname?><$var</h1>
```

How do I transmit it?

Comment: You take the wrong aproach. Possible solutions are: a) create website.php and use your php data there; b) use JavaScript ajax requests to get data from test.php (test.php has to return this data first as a response to call)

Comment: thanks, how would solution b) look like?

Comment: more or less like @Ferdinando suggested. The only think that you don't need is to call `$("button").click(function(){})` as you want to see result on page load, not after clicking the button.

Answer (score -1):

example how to use ajax javascript:
Change the text of a h1 element using an AJAX request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test.php", success: function(result){ 
            $("#h1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="h1">Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h1>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

in your test.php file write this one:

```
<?php

$var = "someText";

echo $var;

 ?>
```

I hope that this is helpful you